# What is meant by 'listings for your program'?

Tags: code-documentation

I am writing a program in Java for a university project, part of the write up report states:

'You must provide listings for your program'

Can anyone provide me with some clarification on what is meant by this?

I have looked high and wide online but nothing i've come across has helped clear this up for me. I found a definition 'With computer programming, a program listing is the complete listing of a computer program, source code, and all files that make up the software program', but his hasn't helped with my understanding of what is being asked in the report.

Should I be providing screen-grabs of my code? Or a screen-grab of the folder with all related files?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Screen grabs are useless. They want to be able to inspect and potentially run your code. It means that you need to provide your source code as text.

Comment: Thanks, @AndyTurner. In your opinion, if i have to provide the executable application on submission anyway, would this count as providing listings or should the source code be pasted as text into the report?

Comment: The most able ones that could answer this are your teachers.

Comment: What you found and @AndyTurner said is correct. But did your teachers said how you should give them the sofware? (for instance push it to some repository or whatever?)

Comment: @jhamon I have asked my teacher for clarification on this point but I was just directed to a definition of the term 'program listing'.

Comment: @Matteo we have to submit a zip folder containing our source code and the executable software. Do you think this will suffice as providing listings?

Comment: @Ginge3030 I would say yes (remember to include steps to build from sources), as jhamon said, if possibile would be helpful to ask the teachers.

Answer (score 1):

A listing of your program used to mean the code of your program rendered into printed form; i.e. on paper.  These days, it could also mean that the source code is formatted and included as a PDF file, or a Word document or something else.

> Should I be providing screen-grabs of my code?

It is unclear if that is what your lecturer wants.  I don't expect so, because screenshots are harder to read than formatted text.

> Or a screen-grab of the folder with all related files?

That is highly unlikely, IMO.  If that is what your lecturer wanted they would have said "directory listing" not "listings for your program".  (And that would be useless for assessment purposes.)

---

But my advice is to ask your lecturer if you are at all unclear what is required of you.

And if your lecturer is unwilling to explain, just do what *you* think is correct.

Comment: "But my advice is to ask your lecturer if you are unclear what is required of you." This. S/he will know better than a bunch of random strangers.

Answer (score 0):

What you find is correct, you need to give source code and any other resources needed to build and run the softaware.

One options could be to :
- pack my project with some build manager (maven, gradle, etc)
- push it to some repository (like github) with a README.md for building and running
- give the github project reference.

If you prefer not to make public the code, just pack it and send an archive with the maven project.

Comment: This advice is not relevant.  The Question is asking about how code should be submitted for assessment in University course.  And specifically, how to interpret what the lecturer means by the sentence "You must provide listings for your program."

Comment: @StephenC yep i see your point... but I was thinking at some nice and widespread way to do that (many courses distribute study examples using github or gitlab for instance).

Answer (score 0):

They are looking for a nice printed output of your source code.  In olden days (pre 2K) compilers would produce a output, well formatted (often with a list of symbols and line number to aid in understanding the code.